# SDN 4.0 multi labels for one @NodeEntity

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have my existing `@NodeEntity` as below

```
@NodeEntity
public class Company {

@GraphId
private Long id;

private String name;

private String blah;
```

and the `@Repository`

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends GraphRepository<Company> {

Company findByName(String name);
```

To create a new `Company` in neo4j, simply do

```
Company company = new Company();
company.setName("Company Name");
repository.save(company);
```

This will create a `Company` node in neo4j with Label `Company`.

However, I also want to be able create this with a different label. Instead of creating a new `@NodeEntity` and a new `@Repository`, can I use existing domain and repo with a separate label to do it?

I had google this, most answers are only applied to SDN 3.*. Some of those suggest to have a collection field annotate with `@Labels`, but looks like this `@Labels` has been removed from SDN4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MicTech pointed out, the only way of achieving this right now is via your object model.

But if you want to attach multiple labels to an existing node entity and repository, it's not possible in the current release. 
You could possibly have a server extension to assign additional labels but those would not really be usable by your repositories.

Unfortunately, we don't have a firm date for implementing this that we can commit to right now because the product road map is still being discussed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a responsibility of [Neo4j-OGM](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm).

For multiple labels for the Node you should use inheritance in Java.

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class DomainEntity { ... }

public class Company extends DomainObject { ... }

public class PublicCompany extends Company { ... }
```